# How to use forEach method for objects in array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach, javascript-objects

Here is an array of donut objects.

```
var donuts = [
  { type: "Jelly", cost: 1.22 },
  { type: "Chocolate", cost: 2.45 },
  { type: "Cider", cost: 1.59 },
  { type: "Boston Cream", cost: 5.99 }
];
```

Directions:
Use the forEach() method to loop over the array and print out the following donut summaries using console.log.

```
Jelly donuts cost $1.22 each
Chocolate donuts cost $2.45 each
Cider donuts cost $1.59 each
Boston Cream donuts cost $5.99 each
```

I wrote this code but it doesn't work :

```
donuts.forEach(function(donut) {

    console.log(donuts.type + " donuts cost $" + donuts.cost + " each");

});
```

What's wrong?

Comment: You should use donut inside console not donuts console.log(donut.type + " donut cost $" + donut.cost + " each")

Comment: You are trying to access a property of the entire array instead of the looped item (`donuts` vs `donut`) inside the `forEach` callback. That's why it doesn't work.

Comment: Simple typo. Off-topic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of

```
donuts.forEach(function(donut) {

    console.log(donuts.type + " donuts cost $" + donuts.cost + " each");

});
```

change it to

```
donuts.forEach(function(donut) {

    console.log(donut.type + " donut cost $" + donut.cost + " each");

});
```

You are looping through the `donuts` array and calling each object a `donut`, but in your code, you are still trying to reference `donuts`.

Comment: Omg I was so close :) Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

donuts.forEach(function(donut) {
console.log(`${donut.type} donut costs $${donut.cost} each`)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).